# Is There a Specification for MOF Comment Delimiters

Tags: comments, dsc, meta-object-facility

[This MOF Format Specification](http://www.wbemsolutions.com/tutorials/CIM/cim-mof-bnf.html) is riddled with C-style ("//") comments but the the allowed structure of actual MOF file comments are not shown in the BNF (which uses BNF improperly, IMO: "aliasIdentifer = "$" IDENTIFIER // NO whitespace !").

I have found many examples of MOF files that use:

```
/* comments */
// comment
```

But these were not in the context of defining the MOF format itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the DMTF specification, MOF files support "// ..." and "/* ... */" for comments.

See section "5.4 Comments" of http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0221_3.0.0a.pdf for details.

(Link found at http://www.dmtf.org/standards/cim - first document in the the "DMTF Specifications" section, titled "DSP0221").

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389748(v=vs.85).aspx). It was in the context of compiling, rather than creating, MOF files.